# docker unable to create mount path and fails always

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker unable to create mount path /foo/logs, which is being shared across all containers in my docker-compose file. This error happens occasionally and not sure what is causing this. We have to restart docker or the machine to get around this problem now on the latest version of docker-compose

```
volumes:
  - /foo/logs:/app/service/logs

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml --env-file=.env.qa up -d

Starting foo-service-container ... error

ERROR: for foo-service-container  Cannot start service foo-service: error while creating mount source path '/foo/logs': mkdir /foo: read-only file system

ERROR: for foo-service  Cannot start service foo-service: error while creating mount source path '/foo/logs': mkdir /foo: read-only file system
```

Various containers have their respective volume setting as follows, so all container logs are spooled to a single location in a machine. Not sure how to make this robust

```
  - /foo/logs:/app/foo-service/logs
  - /foo/logs:/app/foo-service1/logs
  - /foo/logs:/app/foo-service2/logs
  - /foo/logs:/app/foo-service3/logs
  - /foo/logs:/app/foo-service4/logs
```

Comment: Use a volume instead of an fs mount

Comment: isn't the above a volume since its declared under /foo/logs

Comment: I have added more information on how other services spool their logs as well

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Use a docker volume rather than an fs mount. You have a File System (fs) mount. In all cases, a docker volume is preferable.

Comment: I do not think it is related to the binding of /foo/logs as source (left side) because the error appears when docker attempts to create the directory in the container. Do you use /foo/logs somewhere as target (right side) as well?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `/foo/logs` filesystem is mounted as read-only.
Use `mount | grep "/foo/logs"` to check the options for the `/foo/logs` and re-mount if needed - something like `mount -o remount,rw /foo/logs` (I'm assuming `/foo/logs` is not under your root file system).

Also, bind mounts between multiple containers might result in issues. Ownership of files might become messy - use volumes instead.

Comment: its not a separate mount, but its part of the root filesystem and hence cannot use your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Docker is trying to create a directory that will then be mounted into the containers.

If you try to create the directory by yourself, ie `mkdir /foo/logs` you'll get a similar error.

This is unrelated to Docker and the problem resides in your permissions on that specific path.

Isolate the issue from Docker by changing all source paths (the part before the `:`) to a directory on which you have write access, for example `/tmp/foo`.

Note the issue is not with `/foo/logs` but with `/foo`, as the message says it can not create `/foo` in a read-only system; it did not even reach the point of creating `logs` inside `/foo`.